# Bind id to doctrine statements

Tags: symfony, entity, formbuilder

I have three tables. One ist the user table, where the users are stored. The other is a location-Table where locatiosn are stored. In the third table, the cleint ID is stored.

Each user got a client ID, each location got a client ID too.

I would like to create a choice field, which list only locations where the cleint id is the same as the user got.

actually, it is like this:

```
$this->createFormBuilder($user)
->add('locations', 'entity', array('class' =>'PrUserBundle:Location','property' => 'name'))
//......
->getForm();
```

This will result ALL stored entries. Is there a way to select only the one with the same client ID as the user has?

So what I mean in SQL is SELECT * (OR WHATEVER) FROM location WHERE client_id = {userdata.client_id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `query_builder` option to your field which will be whatever query you like.

So something like:

```
$this->createFormBuilder($user)
    ->add('locations', 'entity', 
         array('class' =>'PrUserBundle:Location',
               'property' => 'name',
               'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                     return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                               ->where(...)
                               ->(...)
                               ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                  })
         )
```

Check [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) for more info

Comment: Thanks that cool. I will check it right now. but, is there no other possibility e.g. that I can do this by entity. SO that I can tell the field Locations that it only accept locations where the same cleint ID is used as the one with which the user is logged in?

Comment: you are doing it by entity - in `query_builder` you change standard query `select * from entityTable` to whatever query you like. In this case `select * from entityTable where user_id = :user_id`

Comment: :) Ops sorry, I meant doing it by annotation directly inside my User Class.